# Always a winner with PHP Hangman

Tags: php

I am getting an error with this PHP implementation of hangman using the exact same [source code from Symbolwebdesign's Hangman](http://www.hangman.symbolwebdesign.nl/sourcecode.php?lang=PHP).

When I put [the script on my server](http://www.littlehousegardening.com/hangman/hangmanfinal.php) and try to play the game, it just keeps saying "you win!" when I enter just one letter.

I am using a text file called words.

Here's the code being used:

```
// The following function returns a word of dots, each dot represents a letter

function word2dots($word) {
$wordlength = strlen($word);
$dotWord = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $wordlength; $i++) {
$dotWord = "".$dotWord.".";
}
return $dotWord;
}

// The following function opens the file, reads it, saves it into an array and returns a random word

function getWord() {

// Opening and reading file

$filename = "words.txt"; // You can change this into whatever words file you'd like, as long as it's local.

@$filehandle = fopen($filename,"r");
@$filecontent = fread($filehandle,filesize($filename));
@fclose($filehandle);

if (!$filehandle) {
$_SESSION['message'] = "Could not open ".$filename;
}

// Splitting the content into the $words array

$words = split("\|", $filecontent);
$words_amount = count($words);

// Calculating random number

$random_number = mt_rand(0,$words_amount);

// Returning random word
$theWord2 = $words[$random_number];

return $theWord2;
}

// Resetting the message

$_SESSION['message'] = "";

// Retrieving the guessWord, theWord and the amount of errors.

if (isset($_POST['send_letter']) && $_SESSION['gameEnded'] != true) {
if (isset($_POST['HangManLetter']) && preg_match("/[A-Z\s_]/i", $_POST['HangManLetter']) > 0) {

// Getting the $letter value

$letter = htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['HangManLetter']));

// Retrieving session variables

$theWord = $_SESSION['theWord'];
$guessWord = $_SESSION['guessWord'];
$error_amount = $_SESSION['error_amount'];

// Checking wether the $letter occurs in the word

// Filling the arrays:

for ($d = 0; $d < strlen($theWord); $d++) {
$theWordArray[$d] = substr($theWord, $d, 1);
$guessWordArray[$d] = substr($guessWord, $d, 1);
}

// Checking occurance of the letter in theWord

$letterOccured = false;
for ($f = 0; $f < strlen($theWord); $f++) {
if ($theWordArray[$f] == $letter) {
$letterOccured = true;
$guessWordArray[$f] = $theWordArray[$f];
}
}

// Updating the guessWord:

$guessWord = "";
for ($r = 0; $r < strlen($theWord); $r++) {
$guessWord = "".$guessWord."".$guessWordArray[$r]."";
}

$_SESSION['guessWord'] = $guessWord;

if ($_SESSION['guessWord'] == $_SESSION['theWord']) {
$_SESSION['message'] = "You won! <input type='submit' name='reset' value='Try again?' />";
unset($_SESSION['theWord']);
unset($_SESSION['guessWord']);
$_SESSION['gameEnded'] = true;
$_SESSION['guessWord'] = $theWord;
}

if ($letterOccured == false) {
$error_amount++;
$_SESSION['error_amount'] = $error_amount;

// If the error_amount is higher as 9, the player lost

if ($error_amount > 9) {
$_SESSION['message'] = "You lost! <input type='submit' name='reset' value='Try again?' />";
unset($_SESSION['theWord']);
unset($_SESSION['guessWord']);
$_SESSION['gameEnded'] = true;
$_SESSION['guessWord'] = $theWord;
}
}

} else {

// Showing the message

if (preg_match("/[A-Z\s_]/i", $_POST['letter']) < 0) {

$_SESSION['message'] = "Only alphanumeric symbols are allowed!";

} else {

$_SESSION['message'] = "Enter a letter!";

} // End of else isaplha ($_POST['HangManLetter'])
} // End of else isset($_POST['HangManLetter']) and preg_match("/[A-Z\s_]/i", $_POST['HangManLetter'])

} else { // If the game has been resetted or there has not yet been a game played

$theWord = getWord();
$guessWord = word2dots($theWord);
$error_amount = 0;
$_SESSION['theWord'] = $theWord;
$_SESSION['guessWord'] = $guessWord;
$_SESSION['error_amount'] = $error_amount;
$_SESSION['gameEnded'] = false;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Hangman</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('HangManInput').focus()">
<div style="background-color:#EFEFEF;position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; border:2px ridge #BBBBBB; width:200px; height:280px; font-family:Times New Roman; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; text-decoration:none;">
 <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return true;">
  <div id="HangManTitle" style="font-size:22px; position:absolute; top:5px; width:200px; text-align:center;">
   Hangman
  </div>
  <div id="HangManConsole" style="font-size:16px; position:absolute; top:34px; text-align:center; width:200px;">
   Enter a letter: <input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" id="HangManInput" name="HangManLetter" /><input type="hidden" value="true" name="send_letter" /><input type="submit" value="Go" name="send_letter_button" /><br />
   The word: <span id="HangManGuessWord"><?php echo $_SESSION['guessWord']; ?></span><br />
  </div>
  <div id="HangManImage" style="position:absolute; top:85px; left:22px;">
   <img src="http://www.hangman.symbolwebdesign.nl/hmimgs/hm<?php echo $_SESSION['error_amount']; ?>.bmp" id="HangManIMG" style="border:1px ridge #BBBBBB;" />
  </div>
  <div id="HangManMessage" style="font-size:16px; position:absolute; top:250px; width:200px; text-align:center;">
   <?php echo $_SESSION['message']; ?>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated in figuring out why it doesn't work and why the game always ends at one letter.

Comment: Gotta love code that suppresses errors. Remove the @ sign from line 23 24 and 25 and see what error comes up.

Answer (score 4):

There is an erroe being displayed in the page **"Could not open http://www.littlehousegardening.com/hangman/words.txt"**, this could be the issue.

Make sure the file words.txt is in right path..

Comment: Alright, I fixed the path and the @ signs.  But I still get the "you win!" without even guessing letters.

Comment: Am unable to browse to the page http://www.hangman.symbolwebdesign.nl/sourcecode.php?lang=PHP Can you verify if the URL is correct?

Comment: Yes the url is correct... make sure you have http://www.  ..... It can also be found here http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet267046.html

Comment: I downloaded the file, created a file by name words.txt in the root and opened the PHP page, I got no errors and the game was working fine....